# Access denied when using window.moveTo

Tags: javascript, html, access-denied

I have a problem when using window.moveTo() in IE (IE8), it pops up the 
"Access denied" error..

Do you have any workaround here?

Thank you.

Comment: Please include relevant link to site or paste in relevant code.  Is the window you are trying to operate on the same domain as the one you're running the code from?

Answer (score 0):

Its security issue . Try to open blank page and move it and I think it will be fine. You can add your URL as trusted site , it should help .